Connection between Access Database and HTML Browser interface
I have a Microsoft Access Database with 5 tables and a html browser webpage.
I need to connect the database with the web so it can read and write my data from every table.
Any ideas?
Tried with  a code using php but it said the database was not found.

This is a complex topic. If you have code with issue, post it in question for analysis.
